# Postgres - does DISTINCT ON take preference for non-null values in column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I use `DISTINCT ON` on 2 columns, and there is a third column that can have null values, does `DISTINCT ON` always try to return a row where that third column is not null, or is it just down to the `ORDER BY`?

So for example with this table:

```
col1    col2   col3
1       88     8
1       88     9
1       88     1
2       88     3 
2       88
3       88
```

I want to be able to `SELECT DISTINCT ON (col1, col2)` and get rows where `col3` is not null, unless the `DISTINCT ON (col1, col2)` does not have a row where `col3` is not null.

Comment: Can you update the question with expected result

Comment: It doesn't need to have a strict expected result though. It could be any combination of distinct col1, col2 so long as when col3 has any non-nulls for that distinct col1, col2, it will return a row without a null.

Comment: Your current explanation made 3 people's to think in three different ways

Comment: It sounds like you are asking about `DISTINCT ON`, which is different than `DISTINCT`. You might want to add some caps and/or backticks to make it more explicit.

Comment: I already got the answer that works below, but I edited the question just to make it more clear that I'm using DISTINCT ON.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is entirely based on what you `ORDER BY`. If you want to prefer rows with a non-`NULL` `col3`, just include that in your ordering:

`SELECT DISTINCT ON (col1, col2) ... ORDER BY col1, col2, col3 ASC NULLS LAST`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct col1, col2, col3
from table t
where t.col3 is not null
 or not exists(select 1 from table tt 
    where tt.col1 = t.col1 and tt.col2 = t.col2 and tt.col3 is not NULL)
```